# Prolem with fetch assoc (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with PHP 5, I do a while for the last results of my table like this :

```
while($news = mysql_fetch_assoc("SELECT * FROM acts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5"))
```

But I receive the following message

**Warning**: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in

Comment: you need to go back and read the docs on how to query a DB, the fact that the `mysql` functions are deprecated in `php5`, etc.
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using it wrong, you shouldn't pass the query to the `mysql_fetch_assoc` function but:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM acts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
while($news = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
     // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass a resultset to mysql_fetch_assoc(), not a query.

```
while($news = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM acts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5",$con)));
```